# angular not working in laravel

Tags: javascript, php, angularjs, laravel-5

I cannot get simple angular code work in Laravel, though I tested it in codepen and it works.

in my gulp I have angular. And I tried also to comment all other scripts (and delete already copied scripts from resources/js directory) to test only with angular.

**gulp.js**

```
elixir(function(mix) {
 mix
 // .copy('vendor/bower_components/jquery/dist/jquery.js', 'resources/js/1-jquery.js')  
 // .copy('vendor/bower_components/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.js', 'resources/js/2-bootstrap.js')  
  .copy('vendor/bower_components/angular/angular.js', 'resources/js/3-angular.js')  
 // .copy('vendor/bower_components/lightgallery/dist/js/lightgallery-all.js', 'resources/js/4-lightgallery.js')  
 // .copy('vendor/bower_components/lightslider/dist/js/lightslider.js', 'resources/js/5-lightslider.js')  

  .scriptsIn('resources/js') 
  .version([
      'public/css/app.css',
      'public/js/all.js'
      ])  
});
```

**blade.php**

```
{!! Form::open(array('route' => 'order', 'class' => 'go-right calculator', 'files' => true, 'ng-app' => 'SaunaDoorCalc', 'ng-controller' => 'SaunaDoorCalcController')) !!}

    <div class="form-group door_size_radio col-xs-12 col-sm-6" style="margin-bottom:67px;"><h4>Размер дверной коробки (в миллиметрах)</h4>
        <div ng-repeat="a in sizeswitch" class="form-group">
        <input type="radio" value="@{{a.value}}" name="door_size_radio" class="radio">
        <label for="door_size_radio" class="radio">@{{a.label}}</label>
        </div>
    </div>
{!! Form::close() !!}
```

**app.js**

```
angular
  .module('SaunaDoorCalc',[])
  .controller('SaunaDoorCalcController', function($scope) {

    $scope.sizeswitch = [           
      { value: 'standard', label: 'Стандартный' },
      { value: 'special',  label: 'Ввести размер' }
    ];


    $scope.submit = function() {
      alert('submit');
    };


    $scope.myDate = new Date();
    $scope.minDate = new Date(
      $scope.myDate.getFullYear(),
      $scope.myDate.getMonth() - 2,
      $scope.myDate.getDate());
    $scope.maxDate = new Date(
      $scope.myDate.getFullYear(),
      $scope.myDate.getMonth() + 2,
      $scope.myDate.getDate());
  $scope.onlyWeekendsPredicate = function(date) {
    var day = date.getDay();
    return day === 0 || day === 6;
  }
  });
```

In output webpage I see `{{a.label}}` and only once, not twice.

I found this error in js section

```
Error: [$injector:modulerr] Failed to instantiate module app due to:
[$injector:nomod] Module 'app' is not available! You either misspelled the module name or forgot to load it. If registering a module ensure that you specify the dependencies as the second argument.
http://errors.angularjs.org/1.5.6/$injector/nomod?p0=app
minErr/<@http://site.dev/build/js/all-6fc346934b.js:12247:12
module/<@http://site.dev/build/js/all-6fc346934b.js:14280:17
ensure@http://site.dev/build/js/all-6fc346934b.js:14204:38
module@http://site.dev/build/js/all-6fc346934b.js:14278:14
loadModules/<@http://site.dev/build/js/all-6fc346934b.js:16786:22
forEach@http://site.dev/build/js/all-6fc346934b.js:12501:11
loadModules@http://site.dev/build/js/all-6fc346934b.js:16770:5
createInjector@http://site.dev/build/js/all-6fc346934b.js:16692:19
bootstrap/doBootstrap@http://site.dev/build/js/all-6fc346934b.js:13956:20
bootstrap@http://site.dev/build/js/all-6fc346934b.js:13977:12
angularInit@http://site.dev/build/js/all-6fc346934b.js:13862:5
@http://site.dev/build/js/all-6fc346934b.js:43197:5
jQuery.Callbacks/fire@http://site.dev/build/js/all-6fc346934b.js:3187:11
jQuery.Callbacks/self.fireWith@http://site.dev/build/js/all-6fc346934b.js:3317:7
.ready@http://site.dev/build/js/all-6fc346934b.js:3536:3
completed@http://site.dev/build/js/all-6fc346934b.js:3552:2
```

Comment: check console what's in there?

Comment: yes. there is something. Added to initial post

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On the console errors, angular is looking for the module called `app`. Perhaps somewhere in your view file, you use `ng-app="app"` but have not created the module.

Try either one of the solutions below.

**Solution 1:**

In your view file where you bootstrapped your angular app, change the value of ng-app to the name of the module that you created. Assuming that you bootstrapped your app in the body tag and your main module is called `SaunaDoorCalc`:

```
<body ng-app="SaunaDoorCalc">
```

**Solution 2:**

In app.js, change your module name from `SaunaDoorCalc` to `app`.

```
angular
  .module('app',[])
  .controller('SaunaDoorCalcController', function($scope) {
    // your code here
}
```